# Как выделяется память под объекты в Python?

Tags: python, list, memory

Данный код показывает `__sizeof__` объектов

```
a = int(123)
print(a.__sizeof__())

lst1 = [int(123)]
print("{} == {} ({})".format(
    len(lst1) * int(123).__sizeof__(), 
    lst1.__sizeof__(), 
    len(lst1) * int(123).__sizeof__() / float(lst1.__sizeof__())
))

lst2 = [int(123), int(123), int(123)]
print("{} == {} ({})".format(
    len(lst2) * int(123).__sizeof__(), 
    lst2.__sizeof__(), 
    len(lst2) * int(123).__sizeof__() / float(lst2.__sizeof__())
))

lst3 = [int(123), int(123), int(123), int(123), int(123)]
print("{} == {} ({})".format(
    len(lst3) * int(123).__sizeof__(), 
    lst3.__sizeof__(), 
    len(lst3) * int(123).__sizeof__() / float(lst3.__sizeof__())
))
```

Вывод вод такой

```
24
24 == 48 (0.5)
72 == 64 (1.125)
120 == 80 (1.5)
```

В списке должна быть какая-то вспомогательная информация, но она не константная, тогда как выделятся память под объекты в Python?

Comment: А зачем писать `int(123)`, а не `123`?

Answer (score 4):

Простые типы данных в Python в два-три раза больше своих прототипов на C. Разница обусловлена необходимостью хранить количество ссылок на объект и указатель на его тип. А списки, словари и множества, как правило, занимают больше на 1/3, чем необходимо. Это обусловлено реализацией алгоритма добавления новых элементов, который приносит в жертву память ради экономии времени процессора.

Интересная статья на эту тему "[Сколько памяти занимает 1 миллион целых чисел?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193890/)"